# What is our current position on these issues?

Tags: discussion, answering-advice, self-governance

I’ve been noticing an increase in answers that, essentially, consist of nothing but a suggestion or bald assertion and that are often lacking any apparent effort to even format, punctuate, or spell properly.

Since I’m only a recent convert to the pleasures of EL&U, I can readily recall the advice I was provided from more experienced and wiser users concerning the characteristics of a “good” answer – an answer which was likely to be helpful to, not only the OP but also to other users – **aside from being accurate and coherent**. I was advised to contribute at least a modicum of person advocacy derived from first-hand experience, to include links to supporting information from established authorities (when possible), with citations in plain, rather than hypertext (due to the ever-present threat of link-rot), and to use quote-blocks only for direct quotations.

Moderators and more experienced users explained how these components were what made a mediocre answer “good” and “useful.” They explained that including the above mentioned components assisted OPs and other users in their evaluation of the quality of my answers, as well as increasing the likelihood that my answers would garner positive votes, which in turn would enhance my reputation score and grant me access to features of EL&U that were currently unavailable to me. I have found all that advice, and gentle but persistent guidance, to be absolutely accurate and I appreciate and try hard to adhere to it.

From the EL&U Help Center [**Answering**](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from another site or in an answer on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange) make sure you do all of the following:
>
> • Provide a link to the original page or answer
>
> • Quote only the relevant portion
>
> • Provide the name of the original author
>
> Example:
>
> According to Ernest Hemingway - Biographical on Nobelprize.org, Hemingway saw combat when he was a teenager. It says:
>
> After the United States entered the First World War, he joined a volunteer ambulance unit in the Italian army. Serving at the front, he was wounded, was decorated by the Italian Government, and spent considerable time in hospitals....
>
> [other sources, quotes, explanations, etc. necessary to complete the answer]
> Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. And always give proper credit to the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link to it.

**What is our current position on these issues? What is the bottom line on citing to established authority, plain text source attribution, and links?** How should I respond to what appears to me at times to be a flood of OP/Answers that fail to adhere to the site’s protocols?

Comment: "*What should should be my response to ... [things] which fail to adhere to the site's protocols*?" **Downvote them**. In the most egregious cases, flag or vote to delete. Personally, I find most established members of EL&U too shy in their downvoting. SE gives you this power for a reason: use it.

Comment: @Dan Bron - thanks for responding. Yeah, I appreciate the power of the DV, but before I also try to provide some of the same guidance I was given - *at times*. And frankly, what motivates this OP is that I've been somewhat overwhelmed by the numbers, lately. So, before I utilize the DVs for the reasons I brought up, and before politely giving guidance - what is our bottom line on these things? I need to feel some confidence, that my suggestions are valid, that my DV is warranted.

Comment: "Shoddy" and slapped on answers have always been around, the difference being if a user *really* enjoys the site they will, sooner or later, make an effort to comply with standards. They will inform themselves and ask for tips via meta and in comments.And, I suspect this behaviour is reflected in the offline world as well as online.  Those who don't, and are deaf to kind words, never hang around for long. But there are exceptions,  the "free spirits" or the "mavericks", and sometimes it's refreshing to see an answer that disobeys the ‘rules’. You can't change a leopard's spots etc.

Comment: Thanks, @Mari-Lou, for lending me some of your equanimity, I appreciate that. What's the official position on the things I asked?

Comment: The only official stance I am aware of is the policy on attributions, the correct way to format citations, block quotes not code, the correct way to source references. There is a meta post by Andrew Leech, which clearly lays out EL&U and SE's policy.

Comment: [**“New attribution rules”**](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/new-attribution-rules/5196#5196); [What to do about missing source attributions?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4973/what-to-do-about-missing-source-attributions/4981#4981)

Comment: An example of a user who was repeatedly helped, given tips, and clear guidance but who remained stubbornly "deaf". You need to be aware of the user's track history, in this case, despite all the guidance, and detailed comments which *explained* WHY a certain protocol should/had to be followed, the user in question just blindly ignored everyone. http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5279/does-a-question-which-shows-no-research-no-effort-deserve-a-downvote

Comment: This is what happens when you've been here for while. :) You will see it from now on. There's no "official" response; do whatever you feel like doing at the moment, from ignoring or DVing, to helping with comments (canned comments help) or even edits. Don't feel bad about down voting, though, just because you were encouraged. Lots of people don't respond to encouragement.

Comment: I've been threatened with bodily injury more than once.  That's always fun.  :-O I'm still here. They are gone. Not everyone is as nice as you.  :-)

Comment: There is much more down voting on questions (compared to views) than there is on answers, especially compared to the tech sites. Don't be afraid to dv when you see something bad.

Comment: Well, we have the same issue with the questions and everyone acts like whatever they feel like... Human nature.

Comment: The only thing that I have a little qualm about here is the highlighting of web-based resources. For a large number of issues, it's printed resources, (or selected electronic resources that not everyone's going to have access to) that should be regarded as havind sufficient clout to provide real support for an answer (although, there are several exceptions). For example, I don't really think that "Grammar Girl" is an authoritative reference! ;)

Comment: @Araucaria - I'm sorry, could you clarify that please?

Comment: @LittleEva Sure: for a grammar question a good source would be a published grammar of English. Something like, Practical English Usage, by Swann, or toward the higher end something like The Oxford Modern English grammar by Aarts, or CGEL or CaGEL. Links to TEFL websites or self-run grammar style/grammar websites won't really do the job - because so much stuff on there is wrong. With the properly published materials, these are peer reviewed, have often stood the test of time, and reputable publishers are willing to stake their reputation by publishing them. So they're more reliable!

Comment: @Araucaria - sorry for the delay, I posted but neglected to "ping" ya - yes, of course, some references are better than others, however any reference is better then absolutely NO references, wouldn't you say. We can always dispute or affirm a given reference. The issue I've been noticing is simply a bald assertion passing as an answer i.e., "I think 'orange' is the correct answer." Period. But, as others have indicated, this is nothing new. But, then again, from my perspective, it's been happening much more than when I arrived on the scene 7 long months ago. Any thoughts?

Comment: @LittleEva Well, sometimes, I reckon, it's not *that* bad to get people's intuitions about a topic - if they're insightful, but obviously it's better to get a ref. I'm not always sure whether just *some* ref is better than none - 'cuz some peeps will just keep looking for a link till they find some crazy person who agrees with them ;) I think everyone goes through phases on EL&U and ELL too, where things seem to have been much better before, but are now getting worse. I'm never sure if it's 'cuz things go in waves or because of the golden age myth we all had before our honeymoon ended! :D

Comment: @Araucaria - the advantages, for both the OP and other EL&U users, of providing an answer sufficiently complete to stand alone - that is, an answer that includes a personal perspective, supported by a block quote or quotes, linked to an established authority with citations in plain text (in case of link-rot) - seem fairly obvious. **What are the corresponding disadvantages of providing such an answer?**

Comment: On many SE sites, a "bald" answer is often converted by mods into a comment, which seems the correct place for it until someone (possibly the original user) can develop it into a proper answer. There isn't much difference between an answer like "no that's wrong, read this link to see why" and "a good word to use is *ephemeral*". Neither are self-contained, or provide any commentary or analysis. Both are of little use to a later reader unless the follow the link/fire up the search engine (eg to see how "ephemeral" is used, or what shades of meaning it has). Both resemble comments not "answers".

Comment: A cost of leaving "bald" answers hanging about, is either that somebody needs to extensively edit them to make them useful stand-alone answers (so the "answer" is mostly attributable to the editor rather than the author, which does not align well with the rep gamification system) or that they end up duplicated, with someone adding a fuller answer in later but covering exactly the same word or phrase (undesirable for a reader to have to wade through).

Comment: @Silverfish - I feel the same - so my bolded question, *inverted*,  was: **what are the advantages of posting what amounts to a 'bald' answer?** It seems to me all benefit accrues to the person posting the 'bald' answer i.e., it 'saves' them time and effort. Period.

Comment: One difficulty is that with certain (not all) ELU questions, the only possible answer is **an opinion of a native speaker** .. ie the nature of the question, is, a canvassing of opinions of native speakers (perhaps in the given AmE, BrE, whatever, milieu).  "Google Docs" or whatever is of no help in spoken language.  (Some people try to resist this obvious nature of certain ELU questions: there's a kind of pseudo-encyclopaedic, Victoriana, motif on commercial "Pro-sumption" sites like this, and "charitable" pro-sumption sites like "Wikipedia"; but that's just a social issue.)

Comment: Note too that on - oh - the mathematics site, top mathematicians simply *explain the answer*, or indeed, just ... *answer*. They don't quote anything. On stackoverflow, the best engineers in the world just answer questions. By no means should any site (such as this one) follow that common mould: if there's a desire for a "wikipedia-like" vibe (to wit: "this is not opinion! just a collection of references!") .. then fine, any site can (I guess?) do what it wants to help the SE network owners make money; pro-sumption is what pro-sumption does. But it's an observation.

Comment: What does "pro-sumption" mean @Joe Blow?

Comment: it is Alvin Toffler's term for "production" being actually done by "consumers".  this rather (completely amazing) concept is the concept behind things like cash machines, but moreover in the "dot com" many many of the major businesses of our day, like wikipedia, this business we are using here, all the review sites, rental sites, etc..  (BTW I find "pro-sumption" a bit confusing, "consumer-duction" would be clearer! :) ) ... simply google Alvin toffler prosumption,  Wikinomics: How Mass Collaboration Changes Everything, Don Tapscott and Anthony D. Williams ..etc etc

Comment: @Joe Blow - So then Toffler is using pro-sumption as the mirror concept of con-sumption, pro-sumer / con-sumer? Along with the producing-consumer connotations.

Comment: {BTW as a funny curiosity .. the wikpedia entry for "prosumption" must be one of the worst wikipedia entries (and that's saying something).  One of the "writers" muddled-it-up with "prosumer" (i.e., you know, high-end digital cameras, utterly no connection to Toffleresque "pro-sumption") I would click to edit but that's now pointless on wikiped.

Comment: "So then Toffler is using pro-sumption as the mirror concept of con-sumption, pro-sumer / con-sumer?"  No, he's pointing out that (incredibly) there are now business models where **the paying customer, actually does the work**.  This is .. astounding.  it used to be that you went to a bank, and the teller would do all the work for you. Now, you yourself have to type in all the numbers. In the old days, magazines had to pay writers on staff, to make the content.  Astoundingly, on this very site, we, the consumers, willingly spend hours making the content!!

Comment: It used to be that the Yellow Pages or whatever had armies of paid staff actually producing the content; today Zomato or whatver is a "pro-sumpotion" business.  Incredibly, the consumers themselves (willingly!) provide all the content, for free.  Many of the biggest businesses of our day are indeed pro-sumption businesses.  Facebook, Pinterest, dozens of huge dotcoms like AirBnb, etc.  The reviews aspect of Amazon is pro-sumption, as indeed is ebay, etc etc.

Comment: It used to be I'd show up at Emirates with a pile of passports and they'd do everything.  Now before flight I have to enter all the preflight data and indeed "check-in" .. I do it all !  pro-sumption, the consumer does the hard work of production!  A nice deal for business!  :)  Even say Minecraft (the most financially successful Game of any type of all time) is essentially a pro-sumption business: GTA spend 10s (100s?) of millions on making content. Minecraft has never moved a brick: the $30 paying kids make the content, wilingly - it's unbelievable!

Comment: @Joe Blow - Right, and the producing consumer gets something for that, so the question is, does the producing consumer feel the trade-off is adequate? Is your passport reference to the UAE?

Comment: Indeed -- these are big questions.  There may be "blow-back" against "pro-sumption" businesses, who knows. Or they may be here to stay, and how things will be going forward. I have no idea why I left so many reviews on TripAdvisor - probably just ego really. Now I just feel, why would I do that, it's crazy. On this site, say, I can make content and get paid a thousand bucks an hour, or make content like this on here - for free! But for me this is a "fun break". On professional sites, some people actually want the "profile" you know. I personally have never run a "pro-sumption" business,...

Comment: ...but it must be a good feeling :)  "Check it out!  My customers (often paying) are doing all the work!"  Nice!  Regarding Emirates, I just mentioned that airline as an example as I believe it's the biggest!

Comment: @Joe Blow - I don't for a minute buy your 'Emirates' airline fluff. I was able to deduce that you were actually doing black ops in Iraq, based out of Company HQ in the UAE. I'm not so slow as you seem to believe, **J**ames **B**ond! ;-)

Comment: Aii!  Never use clever initials, right!  There's a bit of tradecraft out the window  :O

Comment: @Joe Blow - isn't there a couple other famous operatives with those same initial?

Comment: @Joe Blow - uhuh, uhuh ... **J**ames **B**ond, **J**ason **B**ourne, **J**ack **B**auer ... need I continue, Mr. Blow?